# How do I update multiple records with apex using execute anonymous

Tags: apex, execute-anonymous

I have the following piece of code that I am able to execute to update a single record at a time

```
Opportunity opp = new opportunity(id='006G000000mHTSE', StageName='Transferred', Membership_Status__c='Transferred');
Update opp;
```

If I have 10 records that need to be updated in the same way, how would I go about writing this code in execute anonymous using the ID of each record?

Comment: Pretty much the same way you'd do it via Apex that isn't running via anonymous apex, really. Store your data in a collection (list, map, or set), loop over that collection, store the records you want to update in a list, then perform DML on the list (outside of the loop, DML and queries should basically always _not be_ inside of a loop).

Comment: If you've tried to make the code you've provided so far work on multiple records, showing us what changes you've tried to make so far (along with the full text of any errors you're getting) would be helpful. You can [edit] your question to add more information.

Answer (score 5):

Using a for loop you can modify the field values and perform a DML on the collection.

```
List<Id> oppIds = new List<Id>{'006G000000mHTSE'};
List<Opportunity> opps = [select id from Opportunity where id in :oppIds];
for(Opportunity opp : opps){
    opp.StageName = 'Transferred';
    opp.Membership_Status__c = 'Transferred';
}
update opps;
```

In this example, `oppIds` is used as a filter simply because you gave a record Id in the question but you can modify your query filter to match your needs.

Comment: The query isn't strictly necessary here, but, given the low volume, there really isn't much reason to avoid it either.

Comment: In this scenario it is not but if the OP decides to query a larger volume of data using filters, this is the scalable approach to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Opportunity> lstOpp = new List<Opportunity>();
Opportunity opp = new opportunity(id='006G000000mHTSE', StageName='Transferred', Membership_Status__c='Transferred');
lstOpp.add(opp);
Opportunity opp1 = new opportunity( id='006G000000mHTSF',StageName='Transferred', Membership_Status__c='Transferred');
lstOpp.add(opp1);
Update lstOpp; // 1 DML
```

In the live code , this can also be a loop where lstOpp is formed with all opportunities added. Update lstOpp happens outside the loop to ensure we have a single DML.